# How to acess cached value from Application_start(Global.asax.cs) page to through out project using Hashtable C#?

Tags: c#, hashtable

I created hashtable and added keys and value into it and finally getting cache that hashtable. Now how can I use cached value in all pages using their key?

```
 Hashtable Hashtable = new Hashtable();
 Hashtable.Add("Example1", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Example1"]);
 Hashtable.Add("Example2", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Example1"]);
 Hashtable.Add("Example3", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Example3"]);
 HttpContext.Current.Application["Example"] = Hashtable;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [Dependency Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.0). What you specifically want is to inject the Hashtable using [`AddSingleton`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addsingleton?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.0#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions_AddSingleton__1_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection___0_) so that there's a single instance across the entire application. At this point, ASP.NET should hand you that same object everytime one of your Controller classes requests it in their constructor.

Conventionally, you want to wrap such functionality in a service, and expose that service using only an Interface that you can change the implementation of later.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this particular situation. In any page, we have to create hashtable object and use that object with key to access that value.
Ex:

`Hashtable CacheObj = (Hashtable)HttpContext.Current.Application["Example"];`

```
string str = CacheObj["Example1"].ToString()
```